# chrome.storage set\get clarification

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, storage, google-chrome-storage

I want to save information in my extenstion. I use `Chrome.storage.sync` to do that, however when I read right after saving I am unable to rightly retrieve the value. Probably doing something stupid....
I tried clearing the local storage with [`chrome.storage.sync.clear`](http://developer.chrome.com/stable/extensions/storage.html) but that did not help.

My save function is (looked at how [Currently](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/currently/ojhmphdkpgbibohbnpbfiefkgieacjmh?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon) did it):

```
save: function (type, key, data) {
    Storage.storageOption(type).set({key:data}, function () {
        console.log("saved data");
    });

load: function (type, key) {
    Storage.storageOption(type).get(key, function (object) {
        console.log("read : " +object);
        return object[key];
    })}
```

and calling it as:

```
Storage.save("", 'path',username);
console.log(Storage.load("",'path'));
```

Which results in this:

> saved data
>
> undefined
>
> read : [object Object]

---

### Update:

OK, apparently there is a problem in how I pass the object's key-value pair because when I call it like this:
`chrome.storage.sync.set({'path':username}, function(){});`

Printing the storage in the console results in a better output:

> undefined
>
> shai

Still not sure what this undefined is...

---

### Update 2:

After successfully writing to the storage, trying to read it when document ready is fired. 
Using the following code:

```
var dbdata = chrome.storage.sync.get("path",function(object){
    return object['path'];
});
```

However, the function's body is not executed, although the documentation says it will be run in any case and will set lastError in case of an error.

Any suggestions?

Comment: returning the value from the function you pass to chrome.storage.sync.get does not do what you expect.  The value is only available within the callback.  It does not end up in dbdata

Comment: That was it! Stupid scope issue. I've updated your answer with this comment and marked answer. Thanks.

Comment: Using {key:data} is the same as {'key':data}.  You need to create an object if the key is going to be dynamic: var values = {}; values[key] = data;

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The returning value from the function you pass to chrome.storage.sync does not do what you expect. The value is only available within the callback. It does not end up in `dbdata`.

In addition:

`chrome.storage.sync` is an asynchronous API.

You have to wait for it to complete before you can retrieve the data.

```
chrome.storage.sync.set({'value': 12}, function() {
    chrome.storage.sync.get("value", function(data) {
      console.log("data", data);
    });
  });
```

and the output is:

```
data Object {value: 12}
```

manifest.json must contain:

"permissions": [
    "storage"
  ],

Comment: The above was just to test why I'm not getting what I want - but well pointed. I am still not able to read the data properly from the storage which is something I am trying to do at document ready event. Also, running in console `chrome.storage.sync.get(null, function (Items) {console.log(Items)});` prints `undefined object{}` so the above might not be the only problem

Comment: changing my code to: `Storage.save("", 'path',username).then( console.log(Storage.load("",'path')));`  results in printing: `undefined 
saved data 
read : [object Object]`

Comment: I've edited my answer after trying the above code and it works fine in the latest version of chrome.

Comment: I'm not following this at all. What if I just want to *get* the data, but not *set* it first? Is it really necessary to always know whats going into the stored data before you can get anything out of it? What's the point of even storing the data?

Comment: if you know the key, and there is some value, you can call `get`, no need to use `set` first.

Comment: Oh, I see; I thought the 'get' required the 'set', thanks for clarifying!