# Chrome.storage not performing as expected

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I tried to implement the solution to the previous question here:[chrome.storage set\get clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14613403/chrome-storage-set-get-clarification/26631204#26631204)

Does this answer still work? Because I used the example given (and have tried the others knocking about, but none seem to work for me.

The code in question is:

```
chrome.storage.sync.set({'value': 12}, function() {
  chrome.storage.sync.get("value", function(data) {
    console.log("data", data);
  });
});
```

and I have the permissions in the Manifest, but the result is:

```
data Object {}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Works for me.. That exact code produces expected result. But, you're using `sync` storage, that has hard rate limits. Try adding `console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError)` before `get` inside the callback.

Comment: It seems to be working now! I am a little confused as to why it was not working before. Thanks for the help