# Chrome.storage.sync.set/get isn't working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-cloud-storage

A common problem that you may encounter when building a chrome extension is that every time you retrieve data from the chrome storage, it returns UNDEFINED. Let me show an example.

```
var toStore = "This text shall be stored"
//Script saves toStore and callback function provides confirmation
chrome.storage.sync.set({"value": toStore}, function(){console.log("Value Saved!")});
```

And then a function is activate by an event that gets the value:

```
var storedItem = chrome.storage.sync.get('value', function(){
console.log("Value Got! Value is " + value)});
```

or something like that, but it your result in the console is always:

```
Value Got! Value is Undefined
```

I will show you how to avoid this. This also will work with chrome.storage.local.set.

Comment: I would never think `ar storedItem = chrome.storage.sync.get('value', function(){
console.log("Value Got! Value is " + value)});` would ever log anything other than undefined, or the value of some locally defined variable called value. Seems like you're answering a problem only people with very small understanding of javascript would ever have

Comment: possible duplicate of [chrome.storage set\get clarification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14613403/chrome-storage-set-get-clarification)

Answer (score 1):

When you get a stored value with chrome.store.sync.get, the actual function does not return the saved value. Instead, it returns var "data" which contains the name-value pairs of the stored value:

```
chrome.storage.sync.get('value', function(data){
console.log("Value Got! Value is " + data.value)});
```

The value is then stored in the function under the name "data.[VALUE-NAME]". If you run this, you should get

```
Value Got! Value is This text shall be stored
```

Comment: this is nothing new. and is already covered in other s.o. questions. and is clearly explained in the official docs.